# How to merge lines with fixed interval in a file?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file and its content looks like this:

```
a1
b1
c1
aa
bb
cc
aaa
bbb
ccc
d1
e1
f1
dd
ee
ff
ddd
eee
fff
g1
h1
i1
gg
hh
ii
ggg
hhh
iii
```

What's the best way to merge the rows with fixed interval (3 in this case) and get something like:

```
a1 aa aaa
b1 bb bbb
c1 cc ccc
d1 dd ddd
e1 ee eee
f1 ff fff
g1 gg ggg
h1 hh hhh
i1 ii iii
```

The algorithm to get the out put from the input is:

- First we get row 1 which is a1.
- We know the interval is 3
- So row 1, row (1+3), row (1+3+3) should be on the same row
- Similarly, row 2, 5, 8 should be on the same row etc.

Those *a1*, *aa* and *aaa* etc. are just random dummy text and they could be any random string. The point is that there is a fixed interval between *a1*, *aa* and *aaa*.

Currently I use emacs keyboard macro to do this task. However I want to know if there are any better ways to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SatoKatsura OK, I'll update my question.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I added more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're on `gnu`/anything and the number of lines is multiple of 9, you could run

```
split -l9 --filter='pr -3 -s" " -t' infile
```

This splits the input into pieces of nine lines and each piece is piped to `pr -3 -s" " -t'` which columnates it... Depending on the no. of lines and their length you may need to play with `pr` options `-w` and `-l`. See the `man` page for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simplistic solution in awk, hard-coded to pull in three sets at three-line intervals:

```
{
  if (NR > 1 && (NR % 9) == 0) {
    print a "\n" b "\n" c " " $0
    a=""
    b=""
    c=""
  } else if (NR % 3 == 1) {
    if (NR % 9 > 1) {
      a=a" "$0
    } else {
      a=$0
    }
  } else if (NR % 3 == 2) {
    if (NR % 9 > 2) {
      b=b" "$0
    } else {
      b=$0
    }
  } else {
    if (NR % 9 > 3) {
      c=c" "$0
    } else {
      c=$0
    }
  }
}
```

Save that into a file and run `awk -f thatfile < input`.  I'm sure there are smarter ways to do it, but I don't work in awk every day.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit tricky. I don't know of a single utility that can do it:

This pipeline (essentially) reads 9 lines at a time and uses `pr` to format into 3 columns:

```bsh
# there are 9 single hyphens below
paste -d: -- - - - - - - - - - < file | while read line; do
    tr : '\n' <<<"$line" | pr -s" " -T -3
done
```

```
a1 aa aaa
b1 bb bbb
c1 cc ccc
d1 dd ddd
e1 ee eee
f1 ff fff
g1 gg ggg
h1 hh hhh
i1 ii iii
```

This assumes you don't have a colon in your actual text.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple, clear way in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
@(repeat)
@x0
@x1
@x2
@y0
@y1
@y2
@z0
@z1
@z2
@  (output)
@x0 @y0 @z0
@x1 @y1 @z1
@x2 @y2 @z2
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr reshape.txr data
a1 aa aaa
b1 bb bbb
c1 cc ccc
d1 dd ddd
e1 ee eee
f1 ff fff
g1 gg ggg
h1 hh hhh
i1 ii iii
```

There are ways to condense this, but you have to work a little harder to understand them, such as:

```
@(repeat)
@  (collect :times 9)
@line
@  (end)
@  (bind (x y z) @(tuples 3 line))
@  (output)
@    (repeat)
@x @y @z
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Also, here how someone who somewhat knows what they are doing in Awk might implement:

```
        { a[(NR-1)%9] = $0 }
!(NR%9) { print a[0], a[3], a[6]
          print a[1], a[4], a[7]
          print a[2], a[5], a[8] }
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f reshape.awk data
a1 aa aaa
[ ... ]
i1 ii iii
```

And if that coder finds repeated `print` patterns repugnant:

```
        { a[(NR-1)%9] = $0 }
!(NR%9) { for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            print a[i], a[i+3], a[i+6] }
```

TXR Lisp solution:

```
[(opip (tuples 3) (tuples 3) (mappend transpose)
       (mapcar (aret `@1 @2 @3`)) tprint)
 (get-lines)]
```

Run:

```
$ txr reshape.tl < data
```

On command line: use `-t`, drop the `tprint`:

```
$ txr -t '[(opip (tuples 3) (tuples 3) (mappend transpose)
                 (mapcar (aret `@1 @2 @3`)))
           (get-lines)]' < data
```

This works by putting the input through a pipeline which shores it up into
triplets, then triplets of those triplets (basically 3x3 matrices made of nested lists). These matrices are individually transposed and their rows are then apppended together to make one giant list of triplets. These triplets are turned into strings with the `aret` partial application operator an string interpolation, and output with `tprint` which treats lists of strings as lines to output.  The syntax

```
(aret `@1 @2 @3`)
```

expands into something resembling

```
(lambda (. args)
  (apply (lambda (arg1 arg2 arg3)
           `@arg1 @arg2 @arg3`)
         args))
```

Basically it implicitly creates a one-argument anonymous function which treats its argument as a list of arguments to apply to a 3-argument anonymous function where the `@1`, `@2` and `@3` denote the arguments. The body of the function is derived from the original quasi-string expression by substituting these special numeric parameters with machine-generated argument names.